# Вопрос про IllegalArgumentException в java

Tags: java

Известно, что наследники классов исключений наследуют и свойство **Checked/Unchecked** .

Если посмотреть на предков IllegalArgumentException, можно заметить:

**IllegalArgumentException -> GetOptsException -> Exception**

Exception является проверяемым(Checked) исключением.

- Тогда почему **IllegalArgumentException**
     непроверяемое(Unchecked) исключение ?
- И почему компилятор не позволяет 
     создать экземпляр **GetOptsException** ?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Извиняюсь. Полез не в тот пакет. Оказывается в com\sun\org\apache... есть свой IllegalArgumentException.